# Can google cloud pubsub subscription really be deleted automatically?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

From the doc:

> Subscriptions with no activity (push successes or pull requests) for 31 days may be deleted automatically

I need to set up a push message subscription which usage may be very low (a few messages per year) but is vital to the app.

The sentence above from the official documentation made me jump !
Should I rely on google pubsub or move away from it ?
Is there more information on this automatic mechanism ?

Need advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the subscriptions are deleted automatically after 31 days of inactivity in Google Cloud Pub/Sub. If you are only sending a few messages a year, then it sounds like Cloud Pub/Sub might be overkill for your use case. Since you have a push endpoint set up, can you just send the message to the endpoint directly from your publisher as an HTTP request and then consider it processed when you get a 200 response? Or is it the case that your push endpoint may be unavailable for long enough periods of time that you can't depend on that working? With such a low throughput, you don't need a lot of the features of Pub/Sub, e.g., flow control.

If you stick with Cloud Pub/Sub, you have a couple of options:

1. Send a periodic heartbeat message from your publisher to ensure the subscription is not deleted.
2. Check for the existence of your subscription before publishing your message and if necessary, recreate the subscription.

Comment: I've chosen the 1st option. Ty. For this specific subscription, i'm using pubsub as an automatic deliver/retry engine.

Comment: @kamal Are these the only options? I'm also facing an issue with automatic deletions. This is particularly an issue in dev, test, and stage environments for certain functionality which may lay dormant or unchanged for a quite some time. For example, if we don't push builds to our CI server for a couple months because we're not working on anything, we have to then recreate everything. With #2 this works fairly well, and we could check on startup, but for longer running apps, we'd need some kind of timer to keep heartbeats going (which might lead to lots of heartbeats as we horizontally scale).

Comment: At this time, there are no other options. We recognize that this is a deficiency and it is one we are looking to address soon. Stay tuned.

Comment: @jon_wu Wouldn't setting the expiration period of the subscription to "Never" work better?

Comment: @Arpith Thankfully, Pub/Sub has added features over time and this has been improved. An expiration period of "Never" is now an option, but that wasn't an option before. I've added an answer that reflects this for anybody else coming across this.

Answer (score 4):

*Updated answer as of [May 16, 2019](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/release-notes#May_16_2019)*

Google Cloud Pub/Sub has the ability to [modify subscription expiration policies](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#modifying_subscription_expiration_policies).

> To prevent a subscription from expiring, set the expiration period to **never**.

The Pub/Sub Subscriber overview outlines the [lifecycle of a subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#lifecycle):

> By default, subscriptions expire after 31 days of inactivity (for instance, if there are no active connections, pull requests, or push successes). If Pub/Sub detects subscriber activity, the subscription deletion clock restarts. Using subscription expiration policies, you can configure the inactivity duration or make the subscription persistent regardless of activity. You can also delete a subscription manually.